# Example of a map $\psi : R \rightarrow R/I \times R/J$ which is not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am studying the Chinese remainder theorem. There is a theorem:

> Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals in a ring $R$ such that $I+J=R$. There exists a ring isomorphism $R/(I \cap J)\cong R/I \times R/J$.

Define the map $\psi$ by:
$$\begin{align}\psi:R&\to R/I \times R/J\\a&\mapsto(a+I,a+J)\end{align}$$

Here we can show $\psi$ is surjective using the Chinese remainder theorem.

Do we have an example of map $\psi:R\to R/I\times R/J$ which is not surjective? I don't want particular examples because I already know them.

I am interested to find a general map which holds for all $I,J$.just like $a \mapsto (a+I,a+J)$ is surjective for all $I,J$ where $I+J=R$. I am looking for A general map $ R \to R/I \times R/J $ which is not surjection and which holds for any $I,J$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just take $I=J=0$, then $\psi$ is not surjective for nontrivial ring $R$.

Comment: I know these particular examples.  Is there any map in general $\psi : R \to R/I \times R/J$ which is not surjective? Just like $a \mapsto (a+I,a+J)$ is surjective for all ideals  $I,J$ where $I+J=R$

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want an example where there is no such $\phi$ for some $I, J$, where $\psi$ isn't necessarily $a\mapsto (a+I, a+J)$? If you take $R$ to be a field, and $I=J=0$, there is definitely no surjective map no matter how you choose $\psi$, as the image is not a field.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing, because in some cases *every* ring homomorphism $R \to R/I \times R/J$ is surjective.

Example: for integers $m$ and $n$, the *only* ring homomorphism $f \colon \mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is the function $f(a) = (a \bmod m, a \bmod n)$ because $1$ must go to $(1 \bmod m, 1 \bmod n)$ and then additivity of $f$ forces the general formula I gave for the function at all integers $a$. When $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, the function $f$ above is surjective, so your dream of a non-surjective ring homomorphism in all cases is impossible.

Be happy that you know examples of non-surjective ring homomorphisms  $R \to R/I \times R/J$ in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $a\mapsto (\bar a, \bar a)$ is not surjective. For instance, there is no $a\in \mathbb Z$ such that $(\bar a,\bar a)=(\bar 0, \bar 1)$ since the equality means that $a$ is even and odd in the same time.